# Asp.Net MVC : difference between model and Model in Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

While using Html Helpers in Views. If I try to write a lambda expression like "m=>...." . Small m automatically changes into "Model". It usually happens If I choose helper without "**For**" word in it. like DropdownList insted of  DropdownList**For** . Also if I use any other letter for lambda expression it changes into something else.

And **m=>m.name** and **Model.name** also gives the same result if I am not wrong.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

And this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name)
```

In Asp.Net MVC at Views, we have a property called `Model`, which access the `Model` (capital `M`) you are getting from the controller. It is case sensitive.

Html Helper without the `For` word in the name like `Html.TextBox()` or `Html.DropDownList()` are helpers to generate html tags for any other field that is not in the model. Actually, in the first version of asp.net mvc, we did not have the strongly typed view, so, we could not have the `Html.TextBoxFor` for sample, so, we used to use this weakly helpers.

Out of the ontext of MVC, in terms of lambda expression, the name of argument does not matter.

Comment: Actually it can matter. Using `Model =>Model => Model.xxx` (capital M) can cause razor exceptions if you have other code in the view that uses `@Model`, say `<div>@Model.Name)</div>` so avoid using using capital `Model` in HtmlHelper expressions

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, ´Model` with capital M, is the typed property of model on the view.

Answer (score 1):

that happens because of intellisense of visual studio.`DropDownList` expects you to supply a parameter that is `string` not lambda expression. When you try to enter lambda expression it chooses one of the word in the intellisense list. For example if you write **b** and enter **=** it automatically gonna change it to `base=.` To use lambda expression use `DropDownlistFor`.